# Is branch-per-release trunk-based development incompatible with semantic versioning?

Tags: development-process, continuous-integration, semantic-versioning

For the purposes of this question it will be assumed that the [conventional commits](https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0/) spec is used as a version driver for semantic versioning.

Given a project is in active development. Releases are planned but not often enough to warrant CD. Thus a release-from-branch strategy is chosen.

If a release branch were to be created from a specific commit, which could be as far in the past as needed, there rises the issue of managing subsequent patch releases. As a simple example, suppose release `1.0.1` is branched off, and the trunk is currently at `1.0.4-SNAPSHOT`. If the patch commit that bumped the snapshot version to `1.0.3` were to be cherry-picked onto the release branch, thus making CI bump and tag the new head to `1.0.2`, how would one handle it when the need to release off of the 'former' `1.0.2` commit arises?

More generally, how would one handle any kind of backporting on the Major and Minor scale also, as a more general problem? Simply solving this with freezing the version and producing Release Candidate-numbered builds defeats the purpose of semver. Is this an inherent incompatibility?

Comment: I would have preferred to tag this "trunk-based-development" also for classification but I don't have the rep for it.

Comment: Could initial release branches use a minor version increment instead?     Given the low frequency of releases, it sounds as if the way patch version increments are currently used are already more akin to minor versions.

Comment: I'm also leaning toward what Ben is saying. Are you sure that your release contents match the definitions in semantic versioning? If you have releases that are not often enough for CD, then I find it strange that you only have bug fixes and no new or planned changed functionality. I guess it could happen sometimes. Also, what type of product is this? A library, an application, a web API, something else?